# Pandas: Efficiently Adding Multiple Columns To A New Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame called 'features' to which I've added new columns that I've computed one at a time.

For example like this

`features['max_diff'] = max_diff`

Then this:

`features['median_diff'] = median_diff`

And so on.

Looking back over the 22 new columns I created and added line by line, I'm wondering if there's a way to add and name each new column more efficiently.

I know I can do the following for example (but this is exactly the same length just written in one line).

`features['max_diff'], features['median_diff'] = max_diff, median_diff`

Is there a way to refer to the features DataFrame 1 time instead of 22 times (for the 22 new columns) and add all the new columns?

I'm thinking something like this (this doesn't work obviously).

`features['max_diff', 'median_diff'] = [max_diff, median_diff]` (...adding all 22 columns)

There might also be a way to do this with a loop or `apply`, can't quite think how though.

---

Updated in accordance with comments.

I'm basically doing this 22 times with a variation on the `groupby` or `fillna` each time.

```
median_diff = sorted.groupby('bidder_id')['bid_time_diff'].median()
median_diff = median_diff.fillna(median_diff.mean())
features['median_diff'] = median_diff
```

Comment: What indication do you have that it's inefficient?

Comment: Syntactically, because I have to write 'features' 22 times. In my head I'm thinking dplyr-type piping.

Comment: How were `max_diff`, `median_diff`, & co. defined? Why not eschew those variables and assign directly to `features` first?

Comment: Good thought - they are the result of pandas groupby statements. I can edit the question to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [pass a dict to  `SeriesGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once). The keys of the dict become columns in the result, and the values can be callables or names of common stats (such as `'min'`, `'max'`, `'mean'`, `'median'`, `'prod'`, `'std'`, `'var'`, `'sum'`, `'size'`, `'first'`, `'last'`). For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)

N = 100
sorted = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N,2)),
                      columns=['bidder_id', 'bid_time_diff'])
# Add some NaNs to `sorted` to show the effect of `fillna`
mask = sorted['bidder_id'] == 0
sorted.loc[mask, 'bid_time_diff'] = np.nan

grouped = sorted.groupby('bidder_id')['bid_time_diff']  
features = grouped.agg({'median_diff':'median', 'max_diff':'max'})
features = features.fillna(features.mean())
print(features)
```

yields

```
           max_diff  median_diff
bidder_id                       
0          8.555556          4.5
1          8.000000          5.5
2          9.000000          2.0
3          9.000000          4.0
4          9.000000          4.5
5          8.000000          1.5
6          9.000000          4.0
7          9.000000          8.0
8          7.000000          5.0
9          9.000000          6.0
```

Comment: The second option of the very first answer you provided pre-edit worked perfectly! `columns = ['max_diff', 'median_diff']
    for col in columns:                                
    features[col] = globals()[col]`

Comment: Although it "works", using `globals()` is not a very good solution. It would still leave 22 stanzas of repetitive boiler-plate code. I'm glad it worked for you but I can't in good conscience promote that as the solution. There are better!

Comment: Fair enough! I can also get the 'dict to  `GroupBy.agg`' option to work as well, which is probably best in this instance.